# Убрать стандартную пропорциональность при генерации картинок WP

Tags: php, wordpress, изображения

Каким методом можно убрать пропорции для генерации картинки?

Например я добавил кастомный размер для картинки

```
add_image_size('224_269', 224, 269, false);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы картинки генерировались именно с такой шириной и высотой, как задано тут, но когда я генерерую картинки размер их 224x173 и т.п.

Comment: Не рекомендую задавать в качестве имени размер картинки. Лучше когда он отображает назначение формата картинки.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто привел пример :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последний параметр задайте равным `true`. Он отвечает за обрезку картинки (относительно её центра). Также данный параметр позволяет указать позицию обрезки.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) (по-английски)

[Перевод описания](http://wp-kama.ru/function/add_image_size) (по-русски)

**Дополнено**

Покопался в исходниках. Чтобы сохранять картинки с измененными пропорциями, придется или самому их пересохранять или написать фильтр [image_resize_dimensions](http://'image_resize_dimensions'). С фильтром будут проблемы. Потребуется определять когда идет пересохранение именно нужного размера.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно не обрезать картинку а просто сделать ресайз на заданную ширину и высоту картинки

Comment: @Mozz С потерей пропорций?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы картинка была размера который я задал в функции, без пропорции - да